# iOS change design orientation in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to make a design that works on both portrait and landscape. I am doing my design in storyboard. Say, for signup view controller the design is working on portrait mode. But I can't make the design in landscape. I googled for couple of hours, but I can't get any tutorial from where I can move ahead.
Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use autolayouts for that. Here are some tutorials:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints

Please note, for working your app in both orientations, enable portrait and landscape modes in `General Settings->Device Orientation`.